# label-studio Error - There was an issue loading URL from $image value

Tags: label-studio

In label-studio I am trying to import pre annotated json file from other machine  in  my local machine ..

```
[
    {
    "id": 51,
    "file_upload": "12.jpg",
    "data": {
        "image": "/data/upload/4/12.jpg"
    },
    "annotations": [...]
    }
]
```

I copied same image 12.jpg in similar dir on local machine - C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\label-studio\label-studio\media\upload\4\ . But I get error when I start label this image in label-studio

```
enter code hereThere was an issue loading URL from $image value

Things to look out for:

URL is valid
URL scheme matches the service scheme, i.e. https and https
The static server has wide-open CORS, more on that here
Technical description:
URL: /data/upload/4/12.jpg
```

I also changed imagge path in JSON and again imported
`"image": "C:/Users/ABC/AppData/Local/label-studio/label-studio/media/upload/4/12.jpg"` still getting same issue.

Corresponding Source of task
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2lFw.png)

Please let me know if I missed any step.

I followed documentation - https://labelstud.io/guide/predictions.html

Answer (score 1):

It's highly recommended not to use media file uploads in Label Studio. They exist mostly for toy setups, just to try things in a fast way. The recommended way is to use storages, e.g.:

- [S3](https://labelstud.io/guide/storage#Amazon-S3)
- [GCS](https://labelstud.io/guide/storage#Google-Cloud-Storage)
- [Local Storage](https://labelstud.io/guide/storage#Local-storage)

**Problems**

There are two points with uploaded files:

1. Permissions

When you upload a media file to LS, LS creates a record in its database and associate the uploaded file with this DB record. If you try to access /upload/4/12.jpg next time, LS will check permission using the DB record and if the permission check is passed, LS returns a file from the hard drive.

More details: https://github.com/HumanSignal/label-studio/blob/develop/label_studio/data_import/api.py#L613

2. Naming

When you upload a media file to LS, it won't be stored with the same name, Django will generate unique name for it. It's made to avoid rewriting already existing files with the same names.

So, it's pretty hard to repeat the same configuration of a project with uploaded files.

**Solution**

1. Connect the [Local Storage](https://labelstud.io/guide/storage#Local-storage).
2. Copy all your uploaded files to the Local Storage folder on your hard drive.
3. Rename all occurrences in your exported JSON file from `/data/upload/4` to `/data/local-files/?d=<relative_path_from_LABEL_STUDIO_LOCAL_FILES_DOCUMENT_ROOT>/12.jpg`
4. Import modified JSON.

Answer (score 0):

what i did to solve the issue is to use different port for running the application in localhost. This solved the issue for me.

```
label-studio start --port 9001
```

Comment: now i connect to the app via 9001 but still same issue